# Require Group option when running Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook that I wish to run *only* when the intended group of systems is specified.  While I am able specify a group (in this example it's 'staging') via

```
ansible-playbook ./playbooks/setup.yml -l staging
```

There are other groups that would all run if the `-l staging` were removed.  I realize that I could make another playbook for each group where the `- hosts: "*"` were changed to the respective group, however all of the rest of the playbook would be identical.  Is there a way to do this without duplicating/copy-pasta'ing everything?

For additional context here is my current setup path structure

```
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── inventory
│   ├── group_vars
│   ├── host_vars
│   └── hosts
├── playbooks
│   └── setup.yml
└── roles
    ├── common
    │   ├── README.md
    │   ├── defaults
    │   │   └── main.yml
    │   ├── meta
    │   │   └── main.yml
    │   ├── tasks
    │   │   ├── main.yml
    │   │   └── redhat.yml
    │   └── templates
    ├── ...
    │   
    └── ...
```

and this is the rough outline of the `setup.yml` contents

```
---
- hosts: "*"
  vars_prompt:
    - name: ...
      prompt: "..."
      default: false
      private: no
    - name: "bar_a"
      prompt: "..."
      default: false
      private: no
    ...
  roles:
    - { role: foobar, foo: 'bar', foo_a: bar_a}
```

and here is the contents of my `ansible.cfg` file

```
[defaults]
inventory = inventory
roles_path = roles:$PROJECT_HOME/roles
forks = 10
timeout = 15
host_key_checking = False
#log_path=./log/ansible.log
retry_files_enabled = False
callback_whitelist = profile_tasks
transport = smart
gathering = smart
fact_caching = jsonfile
fact_caching_connection = ./.factcache
fact_caching_timeout = 86400

[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ForwardAgent=yes
pipelining = true
```

Comment: You are supposed to have different inventories for this case and execute playbook with `-i staging`.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov thank you for the correct mode of action - would you mind providing an example in the form of an answer.  I attempted to create separate inventories with my current setup and specify in the manner you've mentioned, but I'm getting `[WARNING]: Host file not found: staging` -- I've added extra context above in the case that's important.

Comment: You say you want the playbook to run only when a specific group is specified and then after that you say "There are other groups that would all run if the -l staging were removed".  That suggests other parts of the playbook would run if the -l GROUP_NAME was omitted.

Comment: For `-i` to work, you need to change your environment. See [staging vs production](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html#staging-vs-production). Split your `hosts` into `staging` and `production`.

Comment: @Petro026 - you are right - multiple groups (in fact all groups) will run because I've set the playbook to run for any hosts file with the `*` specified in my hosts file.  The point, however, is I want to run it on only one group at a time and not all groups (say when I'm doing staging work vs local work).  Sorry if I'm not communicating that point well.

Answer (score 1):

The best current answer I've received is that I'm "holding it wrong", and that the currently accepted way of achieving what I'm after is to use multiple inventory files.  Each will have its own set of like groups.

**First:** Change inventory setup to mimic

```
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── inventory
│   ├── default
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   └── hosts
│   └── staging
│       ├── ...
│       └── hosts
:
```

**Second:** update the `ansible.cfg` file to reflect your new default inventory file

```
[defaults]
inventory = inventory/default
...
```

**Third:** update default hosts file (`../inventory/defaults/hosts`) to this

```
# intentionally empty
```

**Fourth:** then make call specifying an alternate inventory file (instead of a different group)

```
ansible-playbook ./playbooks/setup.yml -i inventory/staging
```

*NOTE: attempts to run the playbook without specifying the inventory (ie: `ansible-playbook ./playbooks/setup.yml`) will end early/abruptly as desired*

*NOTE: the use of the `i` (alternative inventory file) and not the `l` (specifying group)*

Answer (score 1):

Splitting out stage and prod inventories into separate files has a lot of advantages, but there's a use case and a decent way to select a group or host to run against at execution time like you describe.

One way to do it is to pass the group name as a variable - in an Ansible environment I work with, we have the convention that playbooks run against the variable `subset`, and we pass that in with the `--extra-vars` (shortform: `-e`) argument at the playbook invocation. So to call a playbook, you run the commandline `ansible-playbook -i inventory/staging -e subset=my-group playbook.yml`.

Most playbooks only want to be run again specific logical host groups, so to keep that restriction you can use Ansible [patterns](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_patterns.html) to specify the intersection of two groups, eg: `webservers:&{{ subset }}`. This lets you avoid trying to install IIS on your Linux hosts, while keeping that flexibility to choose what to run against at the time of playbook invocation...

As a side note, variables set by the set_fact module [won't work here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/3308). This is because variables belonging to individual hosts aren't interpreted by the Ansible interpreter when it's figuring out which hosts to run a whole play against.